# Custom cell in gwt CellTree

Tags: gwt

I've got a CellTree working with simple text cells. 
Now I want, for every tree node, a different kind of cell depending on if it is a leaf or not.

This cells would be:

(1) if the node is a leaf (doesn't have children): a TextCell

(2) if the node is a root (it has >= children):.
    - It must display the same string as the leafs 
    - + 1 clickable image (this is an icon that is used to rename the node's name).
    - + 1 clickable image (this is an icon that is used to remove the node).

I've tried with:

(1) Custom cell, extending AbstractCell. The point here is that I can't get the clickable images to respond to de mouse click. So no action can be performed (edit name or remove node).

(2) CompositeCell. The point here is that altought I get the clickable images to respond on mouseclick, I can't get an implementation that chooses correctly which kind of cell must be displayed (based on if it has children or not, show TetxCell or custom cell with icons).

Could someone explain how I could achieve this? My code so far is:

public  NodeInfo getNodeInfo(T value) {

```
if (value == null) {
  return new DefaultNodeInfo<CellTreeNode>(treeData.getDataProvider(), new IconCell(!isLeaf(value)),
      selectionModel, null);
}
else if (value instanceof CellTreeNode) {
  CellTreeNode node = (CellTreeNode) value;

  //data provider for this cell
  ListDataProvider<CellTreeNode> nodeDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<CellTreeNode>(node.getChildren());

  IconCell nodeCell = new IconCell(this, node, !isLeaf(node));

  // add a reference to the visual representation of the element
  node.setCell(nodeCell);

  return new DefaultNodeInfo<CellTreeNode>(nodeDataProvider, nodeCell,
      selectionModel, null);
}
// Unhandled type.
String type = value.getClass().getName();
throw new IllegalArgumentException(
    "[CellLargeTreeListBox] Unsupported object type: " + type);
```

}

// Check if the specified value represents a leaf node. Leaf nodes cannot be
  // opened.
  public boolean isLeaf(Object value)
  {

```
if (value == null) return false;
CellTreeNode node = (CellTreeNode) value;
return value instanceof CellTreeNode && !node.isRoot();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell won't depend on the value it'll display, but on the value of the *parent* node.

So, you'll need a generic cell that supports both renderings/behaviors and switches between them based on the value it's asked to display: for a value that you can tell is a leaf, then only render text, otherwise also render the images/buttons (note you can also render the same HTML –to make it possible/easier to use a `CompositeCell`– but switch visibility of the images/buttons using CSS (`class=xxx` rendered on a container element).

Comment: Thanks Thomas! finally I'm using a div with display:none attribute for those icons I don't want to display. I didn't try to play with styles... and has been the best solution so far.